# htaccess hide directory name doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I have multiple sites and domains on my server.
I dont know what am I doing wrong but when I switch directories of my site then in address path is showing up main directory path.

/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^example_home_dir/ /example_home_dir%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

When I'm on home page - everything is ok (example.com is showing content of example_home_dir).
When I manually enter domain with sub directory, then everythink working fine too (example.com/subdir is showing subdir content).
When I click anchor with redirect to "example.com/subdir" then server is redirecting me to "example.com/example_main_dir/subdir" and showing subdir content.

I have tried a lot of solutions and nothing worked.
As a curiosity I will say that redirects in my symfony projects working fine.

I don't know what to do :( Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a redirect rule to strip `example_home_dir` from URLs:

```
DirectorySlash Off
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+example_home_dir/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^example_home_dir/ example_home_dir%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Also make sure you always have a trailing slash when you have a URL that points to a directory. So use `example.com/subdir/` instead of `example.com/subdir`.

Make sure to use a new browser to test this change.